# $D_{g\circ f}\subset D_f \cup f^{-1}(D_g)$ when doing the composite $g\circ f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

> Indicating generically with the notation $D_{\phi}$ the set of points
>   of discontinuity of an application $\phi$, show that if the composite
>   $g\circ f$ 'has meaning', then $D_{g\circ f}\subset D_f \cup
>  f^{-1}(D_g)$. Give an example of when this inclusion this is strict.

When we're trying to do the composite $g\circ f$, if $g\circ f$ is discontinuous, what does it say about $g$ and $f$? I can only think that $g$ has a discontinuity at some point in the image of $f$, as even if $f$ is discontinuous, $g$ can still fix it then composed with $f$.

But where does $D_{g\circ f}\subset D_f \cup f^{-1}(D_g)$ comes from? What is $f^{-1}(D_g)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider $g(u)=\dfrac {\sin (\arctan u) }{u}$ and $f(x)=\tan x$.

then $D_{f}=\{x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+n\pi, n\in \mathbb Z\}$, $D_{g}=\{0\}$, and $f^{-1} (D_{g})=f^{-1}(0)=\{x=n\pi, n\in \mathbb Z\}$.

so $D_{f} \cup f^{-1} (D_{g})=\{x=\dfrac{n \pi}{2}, n\in \mathbb Z\}$,but $D_{g\circ f}=\phi$, since in this text we can get $g\circ f =\cos x$, which is continuous for all $x$.

ps. but I think it is cheating anyway…